# How do I connect a Wii Balance Board to Android via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, nexus-4, bluetooth-pairing

Cue the "I've tried nothing and I'm out of ideas"...

---

**What do I want?:**

I want to make a Unity game for Android using the Wii Balance Board as a controller.

---

**What have I researched?:**

The Wii Balance Board uses standard Bluetooth to connect to the Wii. The board **does not** have a passcode. All results for connecting the board to an Android device points to two apps [FitScales](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.paulburton.fitscales&hl=en) and [WiiScale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.broschb.wiiscale) both not compatible with my device. I can't find any other results than these two apps.

---

**What's my question?:**

Why can't my phone (Nexus 4, Lollipop) connect to a device with no pin? (It prompts me to put in a pin and "OK" is greyed until I enter a pin). So how can I get it to connect to my Bluetooth?

Other than Bluetooth, is there any other way to get information from the board to my phone?

---

**Notes:**

- My Windows 8 can connect to my board flawlessly.
- Yes, I've tried tuning my phone and Bluetooth "off and on again".
- Yes, my Bluetooth works.
- Yes, my board works (like I said I could get input from it on my pc).
- My board does appear in my Bluetooth list.
- Any information is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Currently it's impossible for Nexus 4 *running on stock (AOSP) ROM* to connect to Wii Balance Board via Bluetooth.

**Reason**: On JellyBean 4.2, Android changed its Bluetooth stack, and the new one doesn't "support" L2CAP which is used to connect to Wii peripherals.

**Solution**: Some custom ROMs (e.g. CyanogenMod) and custom kernels might fix this issue.

(Specific answer for your case: unfortunately, it's not a good idea to make a Unity game for Android using the Wii Balance Board as a controller)

---

## Details

From FitScales's "what's new" and WiiScale's description:

> - Prevent installation on JellyBean MR1 4.2 due to Google replacing the Android Bluetooth stack. The new stack does not expose the functionality required by FitScales rendering it incompatible for now.
> - **DOES NOT WORK on NEXUS devices or JELLY BEAN or ANDROID 4.2 devices.

Using that clue as the starting point, I found a discussion on [MoDaCo forum](http://www.modaco.com/topic/362349-dust-off-your-wii-fit-balance-board-and-connect-it-to-your-android-device/):

> Post [#4](http://www.modaco.com/topic/362349-dust-off-your-wii-fit-balance-board-and-connect-it-to-your-android-device/#entry2120517): Google broke/removed insecure L2CAP socket support in Android 4.2.x. Wiimotes and other Wii peripherals stopped working because of this. Tell Google to fix/restore this functionality.

And finally, the report on AOSP issue tracker confirms this: [Issue #58164: Support Bluetooth L2CAP](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58164) (consider starring that to follow the progress. Also, there are some constructive technical information posted there).

One thing that might interest you:

> Post [#50](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58164#c50): Alright, so I'm on a Nexus 7 rooted and running the latest official build of CyanogenMod 11. Before I flashed CM, it always asked for a password when trying to connect a WiiMote via straight Bluetooth. Now that I'm running CM, it connects to on without asking for a PIN.

Also, post [#113](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58164#c113) mentions a link to [Android code review](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/137040/) which seems trying to support WiiMote (and possibly other Wii peripherals) on Android's next build. However, it still needs kernel that supports the following:

> ```
> CONFIG_HIDRAW=y
> CONFIG_UHID=y
> CONFIG_HID_WIIMOTE=y
> ```
>
> 3.4 based kernels support only the original WiiMote,
> 3.10 kernels should have native support for 2nd gen WiiMotes,
> Wii U remotes did not make it in until 3.11 kernel release.